# tcsh always double the number of backslashes in history searches

Tags: tcsh

I uses tcsh and when I used search-backward (history), it always double the number of slashes in my previous command:

e.g.:

```
$ some_command -arg "+switches=\\*"
```

And when I pressed up-arrow, it shows:

```
$ some_command -arg "+switches=\\\\*"
```

How can I make my shell not do this?

Comment: I don't have this behaviour with the default config. Do you still have this if you start tcsh as `tcsh -f`? If not, then it's probably something in your (t)cshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in tcsh.  RedHat Bug #1334751 describes this problem, and says it's fixed as of (looks like) June, 2016.  See:

```
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1334751
```

for details.  Note, if you have a long-running shell, you might need to do an "exec tcsh" after updating to be sure you're running the current binary.